# With CSS, how would I align this banner and navigation menu to XHTML 1.0 Strict specifications?

Tags: css, xhtml

As the question states above, how would I go about aligning a navigation menu to a banner regardless of user-end horizontal screen resolution? Since I'm creating a fixed-width layout, fluidity shouldn't matter much. In the end, everything's going to be centered, contained in a specific width. For those curious, I'm trying to design for a 1024px by 768px monitor.

I've attached an image with an area of concern circled in red. In yellow, I've boxed the objective that I hope to resolve.The method should preferably use CSS. It must validate to XHTML 1.0 Strict.

At this point, I'm out of ideas!

[image: Current version of the page]

Comment: What does CSS have to do with conformance to XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put everything, including the menu, inside the same wrapping div element and set width as well as centering (margin: 0 auto) to that element.

Also, CSS doesn't validate to XHTML - it validates to CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I finally figured out a different solution with "position: absolute".

Comment: In hindsight, should have probably phrased my answer in a different fashion. With "position: absolute" and your method, I think I've gotten what I want.

Answer (score 1):

i get this problem quite a lot and people tend to overdo stuff. here's my take on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/g4Xce/2/

just fill in the necessary content and it's ready to go.

should work for IE7+ and all other browsers. do mind the comments. they are important.